# Is there a way to know what driver is making my laptop runs slow?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, updates

I use a software (like Driver Genius, which is called DriverEasy) to download the latest drivers for my laptop, but after install all of them, the laptop runs slow, more than before. So, I want to know which driver is causing that.

Do you know a way to know that?

Comment: This is why those types of programs suck and should be avoided.

Comment: Model of laptop may help here to direct you to "official" drivers.

Answer (score 2):

In the Computer/Device Management tool, roll back the recently installed drivers (and reboot) one at a time until you find the culprit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's quite likely that the tool you're using to download drivers is adware / malware / just-plain-badware and **that** is the cause of the slow speed.

You could always try a system restore to a date before you installed it to see if the speed improves. The only site that one should rely on for drivers is the manufacturer's website.